# Using autocomplete suggestion for two fields

Tags: javascript, php

I want to give auto suggestion for two input fields.for first field auto suggestion is working fine..but in the second field auto suggestion is not working. I have checked twice but can't find what error i have done.

```
$(document).each(function(){
$('#user-searchbus').keyup(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        method:'post',
        url:'../php/ajax.php',
        data:{key:val}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        if(data == ''){
            $("#results").hide().html('');
        }else{
            $("#resultqueries").show().html(data);
            $("#resultqueries div").each(function () {
                $(this).click(function () {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    $("#userqueries").val(text);
                    $("#resultqueries").hide().html('');
                });
            });
        }
      });
    });
    });


//ajax search

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#userqueries').keyup(function(){
    if(val !=''){
        $('#resultqueries').show.html('');
        var cities = [
            'Mumbai',
            'Delhi',
            'Bengaluru',
            'chennai',
            'kolkata',
            'Hyderabad',
            'Madurai',
            'Ahmedabadh',
            'kanpur',
            'nagpur',
            'jaipur',
            'Indore',
            'Thane',
            'Bhopal',
            'Coimbatore',
            'vijayawada',
            'rajkot',
            'Allahabad',
            'Salem',
            'Thiruchi',
            'Nellore',
            'Dhindukal',
            'Sikar',
            'Raichpur',
            'Haridwar',
            'kasi',
            'Thirunelveli'
        ];
        $.each(cities,function(index,value){
          if(value.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0){
              $('#resultqueries').append("<div>"+value+"</div>");
          }
        });
        $('#resultqueries div').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                var text = $(this).text();
                $('#cities').val(text);
                $('#resultqueries').hide().html('');
            });
        });
    }else{
        $('#resultqueries').hide.html('');
    }
   });
    $(".scroll").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
  });
  });
```

my php code is

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','madhi1234','busticketreservation')orDie();
$key = $_POST['key'];
if($key == ''){
echo "";
}else{
$ajaxsuggestionquery =
 "SELECT cities FROM cities WHERE cities LIKE'%".$key."%'";                                                        
$ajaxresult = mysqli_query($con, $ajaxsuggestionquery);
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ajaxresult)) {
    echo "<div>".$row['cities']."</div>";
}
}
```

?>

Comment: You want help with php, but don't provide php code... what is the logic in this?????????

Comment: sorry...now i edited my question ... :)